# regex for in quotation elemenst

Tags: python, regex

i look for this bu there was just between quotation and not after another element.

let me describe more.

i want just fetch in quotation elements which is after a specific element.

look at this :

```
set policy id 1444 name "#####TEMP#####" from "DMZ" to "DMZ"  "10.62.28.178/32" "Any" "ANY" permit

set service "PING"

set policy id 1444
```

i want all the in quotation elements which are after from in a list and ofcourse before new line. i mean :

```
list=['"DMZ"','"DMZ"','"10.62.28.178/32"','"Any"','"ANY"']
```

using `re.findall()` function and the pattern `(\".*?\") \ *` i fetch every in quotation elements in a list which is like below :

```
list=['"#####TEMP#####"','"DMZ"','"DMZ"','"10.62.28.178/32"','"Any"','"ANY"','"PING"']
```

but now i want just the in quotation element which are after from just in a list.

tanks for helping.

Comment: "i want just fetch in quotation elements which is after a specific element." What's the specific element?

Comment: Do you mean you want it without the quotations?

Comment: the words in the quotations. of course just those that are after from in the main code. my purpose is the : list=['"DMZ"','"DMZ"','"10.62.28.178/32"','"Any"','"ANY"'] not list=['"#####TEMP#####"','"DMZ"','"DMZ"','"10.62.28.178/32"','"Any"','"ANY"'].

Comment: @ Acsisr : no, look at the main code. set policy id 1444 name "#####TEMP#####" from ... ok? now i want all the quotations after the from not before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found

```
(?!.*from).*?(\".*?\").*?[^\n]
```

Comment: tanks to vks for first part

Comment: look at the second line : set service "PING", which is in the result. but i don't want that part. cause of that i used [\n].

Answer (score 0):

```
   (?!.*?from)(\".*?\")
```

You can use this.This uses a negative lookahead.

You can also use

```
 print re.findall(r"(?!.*from)(\".*?\")",x)
```

See Demo:

http://regex101.com/r/cC2qY1/3

Comment: It use a neagtive lookahead.in effect that says (?!regex)regex1. match regex1 only if regex does not match.

Comment: @hgh Is it possible that multiple `'from'` are present in string?

Comment: @ Ashwini Chaudhary no just one from.

Comment: the second part says scroll through string and if you get words in \" and \" group it..The first part says do not match any string upto the word "from". " (?!.*?from)(\".*?\") " .The forst part takes out string till from and allows regex to match rest.